# How to pass an argument to the main program in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Each time I run my Hadoop program I need to change the number of mappers and reducers. Is there any way to pass the number of mappers and reducers to my program from command line  (when I run the program) and then used `args` to retrieve it?

Answer (score 7):

It is important to understand that you cannot really specify the number of map tasks. Ultimately **the number of map tasks is defined as the number of input splits** which is dependent on your `InputFormat` implementation. Let's say you have 1TB of input data, and your HDFS block size is 64MB, so Hadoop will compute around 16k map tasks, and from there if you specify  a manual value less than 16k it will be ignored, but more than 16k and it will be used.

To pass via command-line, the easiest way is to use the built-in class `GenericOptionsParser` (described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html)) which will directly parse common command-line Hadoop-related arguments like what you are trying to do. The good thing is that it allows you to pass pretty much any Hadoop parameters you want without having to write extra code later. You would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String extraArgs[] = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    // do something with your non-Hadoop parameters if needed
}
```

Now the properties you need to define to modify the number of mappers and reducers are respectively `mapred.map.tasks` and `mapred.reduce.tasks`, so you can just run your job with these parameters:

```
-D mapred.map.tasks=42 -D mapred.reduce.tasks
```

and they will get directly parsed with your `GenericOptionParser` and populate your `Configuration` object automatically. Note that there is a space between the -D and the properties, this is important otherwise this will be interpreted as JVM parameters.

Here is [a good link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) if you want to know more about this.

Comment: thanks. but what if the parameter that I want to pass is not a configuration predefined parameter and is a user-defined one?

Comment: @Hessam Your question was about passing the number of mapper and reducers, which is already predefined, but obviously if you want to have your own parameters you need to do your own logic, you can get the remaining arguments from the `extraArgs` variable in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of mappers and reducers ( and really any parameter you can specify in the config), by using the `-D` parameter.  This works for all default Hadoop jars and your own jars as long as you  `extends Configured`.

```
hadoop jar myJar.jar -Dmapreduce.job.maps=<Number of maps> -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=<Number of reducers>
```

From there you can retreive the values using.

```
configuration.get("mapreduce.job.maps"); 
configuration.get("mapreduce.job.reduces");
```

or for Reducers

```
job.getNumReduceTasks();
```

Specifying the mappers with the configuration values will not work when `mapreduce.jobtracker.address is "local"`. See Charles' answer where he explains how Hadoop usually determines the number of Mappers by data size.

Comment: thanks. but what if the parameter that I want to pass is not a configuration predefined parameter and is a user-defined one?

Comment: Then you can `set` it in a similar fashion. `configuration.set`, or job.setNumReduceTasks()

Comment: There should be a space between `-D` and the property see for example https://books.google.be/books?id=6BmkBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT205&ots=79NHaZ4PMn&dq=do%20not%20confuse%20setting%20hadoop%20properties&hl=nl&pg=PT205#v=onepage&q=do%20not%20confuse%20setting%20hadoop%20properties&f=false

Comment: Both ways are correct. On most shells for *NIX systems, including linux and OSX, '-<letter><argument>' is equivalent to '-<letter> <argument>'. so '-Dvalue' is the same as '-D value'